# Using IIF() after IN with macro substitution variable inside query where clause

Tags: sql-server, visual-foxpro, foxpro

I am trying to accomplish a query as such:

```
select  *
    from table1
    where id1 in IIF(llchoose_flag = .T., (&lcid_list.), (id1))
```

where the character string lcid_list = "1,2,3".

So if llchoose_flag = .T., I want to select records where id1 is in the list defined by the variable lcid_list. And if llchoose_flag = .F., I want to select all records, i.e. where id1 in (id1).
I have also tried using INLIST() but have not been successful with either method.
The error I seem to keep getting is: Function name is missing ), but I don't believe that is true. I am starting to think that it might not be possible to use an IIF() statement inside the IN clause, but maybe I just need to fix my syntax.

I am trying to accomplish this query in either FoxPro or SQL. The above code syntax is my attempt in FoxPro, but it would be very similar in SQL, aside from the macro substitution notation I believe?

I am able to run a FoxPro query such as:

```
select  *
    from table1
    where id1 in (&lcid_list.)
```

So it seems to not like the IIF() after the IN. One way around this would be to store different values inside the lcid_list variable depending on llchoose_flag, but that would involve storing millions of id values in that character string when llchoose_flag = .F. (all id records in table1), which would not be as efficient as an IIF method.

Let me know if anyone knows of a way to accomplish this type of query. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In VFP basically it is:

```
select  * from table1 where !m.llChoose or id1 in (&lcid_list.)
```

In SQL server it would be similar.

However, if you think about it, a statement in VFP cannot go over 8K and thus id count is much less than 4K at max. If it would be a call to SQL server, than that limit is much higher (SQL server side limit is much higher), for VFP side 16 Mb by documentation.

Since the call starts from within VFP, either it is a VFP data or SQL server, it is much better to eliminate if from where and to push that outside, ie:

```
if m.llChoose
   select  * from table1 where id1 in (&lcid_list.)
else
   select  * from table1
endif
```

If it is for SQL server then you could either create a temp table and fill it with either one by one or using a bulk copy activex (search for sqlbulkcopy on foxite.com). Then you would simply do a join.

Another approach is to pass a parameter to SQL server and have it parsed there. SQL server itself is slow at string operations and it might time out with large strings. However you could use CLR functions for parsing. ie: on Foxite check:

[A little handy utility for SQL server](https://www.foxite.com/archives/a-little-handy-utility-for-sql-server-0000422358.htm)

Using that, you can pass your ID list as a string parameter and the length of it could be up to 2 Gb in length (in theory, if you use a memo field as the parameter source), or 16 Mb plain string memory variable. Your code then would look like:

```
lcSQL = 'select * from Table1 t'
if m.llChoose 
   lcSQL = m.lcSQL + ;
      ' inner join ufn_IntsToTable(?m.lcid_list) ids'+;
      ' on t.id1 = ids.v'
endif

lcID_list = "1,2,3"

SQLExec(m.handle, m.lcSQL, 'crsResult')
```

PS: You could also send an XML table and parse on SQL server side for joining (would be slower).

Answer (score 1):

select item from Split(@lcid_list,',')
item

This is code for sql server

```
declare  @lcid_list varchar(100)= '1,2,3'
declare  @id1 int=1
declare  @llchoose_flag varchar(100)='T'

select  *
from table1
 where 
 @llchoose_flag='f' or 
                 
    ( @llchoose_flag = 'T' and id1 in(select item from Split(@lcid_list,',')))
 or ( @llchoose_flag not in( 'F' , 'T') and id1 in(@id1))
```

There is  Split function in sql server(oldest Version), so we need to create user defined function.

```
CREATE FUNCTION Split (
     @InputString                  VARCHAR(8000),
     @Delimiter                    VARCHAR(50)
)

RETURNS @Items TABLE (
     Item                          VARCHAR(8000)
)

AS
BEGIN
     IF @Delimiter = ' '
     BEGIN
           SET @Delimiter = ','
           SET @InputString = REPLACE(@InputString, ' ', @Delimiter)
     END

     IF (@Delimiter IS NULL OR @Delimiter = '')
           SET @Delimiter = ','

--INSERT INTO @Items VALUES (@Delimiter) -- Diagnostic
--INSERT INTO @Items VALUES (@InputString) -- Diagnostic

     DECLARE @Item           VARCHAR(8000)
     DECLARE @ItemList       VARCHAR(8000)
     DECLARE @DelimIndex     INT

     SET @ItemList = @InputString
     SET @DelimIndex = CHARINDEX(@Delimiter, @ItemList, 0)
     WHILE (@DelimIndex != 0)
     BEGIN
           SET @Item = SUBSTRING(@ItemList, 0, @DelimIndex)
           INSERT INTO @Items VALUES (@Item)

           -- Set @ItemList = @ItemList minus one less item
           SET @ItemList = SUBSTRING(@ItemList, @DelimIndex+1, LEN(@ItemList)-@DelimIndex)
           SET @DelimIndex = CHARINDEX(@Delimiter, @ItemList, 0)
     END -- End WHILE

     IF @Item IS NOT NULL -- At least one delimiter was encountered in @InputString
     BEGIN
           SET @Item = @ItemList
           INSERT INTO @Items VALUES (@Item)
     END

     -- No delimiters were encountered in @InputString, so just return @InputString
     ELSE INSERT INTO @Items VALUES (@InputString)

     RETURN

END -- End Function
GO

---- Set Permissions
--GRANT SELECT ON Split TO UserRole1
--GRANT SELECT ON Split TO UserRole2
--GO
```

You can insert Base data  with the following statements:

```
drop table   table1
create table table1(llchoose_flag varchar(100),id1 int)

insert into table1(id1 ,llchoose_flag)values(1,'f')
insert into table1(id1 ,llchoose_flag)values(3,'f')
insert into table1(id1 ,llchoose_flag)values(5,'t')
insert into table1(id1 ,llchoose_flag)values(6,'j')
```

Comment: string_split is not available in SQL server versions prior to 2016 (or even later if compatibility level is not 130 or above).

Comment: I added split function for oldest version and edited my code